# Telerik WPF RadGridView CellEditEnded event issue

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik RadGridView for WPF to display the data.

My requirement is when I end up changing a value in one of the columns then update the data of different columns of same row.

I am using CellEditEnded event to calculate and update other cell's value.

This works when I set the focus to any other cell of different row but if I click somewhere in the cells of same row, it does not update values.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Just added grid.Items.CommitEdit().